# How do I calculate R-squared value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, statistics, regression

I need to calculate the R-squared value (Least Squares Method) for my regression model. How can I do this in JavaScript?

For example I have this data:

```
x = [5, 7, 8, 7, 2, 17, 2, 9, 4, 11, 12, 9, 6]
y = [99, 86, 87, 88, 111, 86, 103, 87, 94, 78, 77, 85, 86]
```

After doing my regression math I got the these coefficients (format: a + bx) `[103.10596026, -1.75128771]` representing the line *y = 103.10596026 - 1.75128771x*.

Now I want to calculate the R-squared value but don't know how... an example function template would look like this:

```
function rSquared(xData, yData, modelCoefficients) {

  // Do stuff here...

  return rSquaredValue

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think [this function](https://gist.github.com/jgphilpott/d38279e8fac9af31054e10b7363bf17e) should do the trick:

```
function rSquared(x, y, coefficients) {

  let regressionSquaredError = 0
  let totalSquaredError = 0

  function yPrediction(x, coefficients) {
    return coefficients[0] + coefficients[1] * x
  }

  let yMean = y.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / y.length

  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    regressionSquaredError += Math.pow(y[i] - yPrediction(x[i], coefficients), 2)
    totalSquaredError += Math.pow(y[i] - yMean, 2)
  }

  return 1 - (regressionSquaredError / totalSquaredError)

}
```

I've tested it on the example data and got this result, `0.5754611008553385` witch also matches the results from [this online calculator](https://ncalculators.com/statistics/r-squared-calculator.htm).